# Allocating 10kb of memory and printing addresses and content

Tags: c, malloc

I want to create a program which should allocate 10kb of memory and prints the memory addresses at groups of 4 bytes and its content. Here is what i want the output to be like:

```
0XAABBCCEB CDCDCDCD
0XAABBCCD8 FFA0B0C0
0XAABBCCD4 00FF00FF
0XAABBCCD0 00000000
```

I don't really know how to get to that output. I know that i need to use malloc and i know that i need to use the right operator to print it in hexadecimal form, but i don't know how to print the content and how to allocate exactly 10kb

Comment: You know that you have to allocate memory? Good. Show us your current effort and we can point you towards the missing details.

Comment: What have you got so far? Show your attempt. How to allocate exactly 10kb is something you can read in any documentation about malloc. Like [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) for instance.

Comment: It's not really that i can't create the program or i can't compile it, it's more that i don't understand the assignment. I know how to allocate memory for an array, using pointers etc and print the address of it but not how to get to that output that the problem is asking, is more of a logical problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define _10KB 10240

int main(){
    int i;
    uint32_t *arr;
    if((arr = malloc(_10KB)) == NULL){
        perror("malloc failed");
    }
    for(i = 0; i < (_10KB/4); i++){
        printf("0x%p  %.8x\n", &arr[i], arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why, i thought i had to use sizeof!

Comment: A few points a) the `_` unscore prefix is usually reserved, b) printing an address pointer should be cast such as `(void*)&arr[i]` and c) you are sending a `uint32_t` value to the `%x` format specifier which expects `unsigned int` and these might not be the same type.

Comment: One thing: why does it print only 0000000 in the content column?

Comment: Also: Names starting with an underscore are reserved for the implementation at file-scope. You must not use them in user code. Oh, and the code invokes undefined behaviour for another obvious reason: you don't allocate enough memory, unless an `uint32_t` is one byte on the target machine. Briefly: the code is flawed and bugged in various places.

Comment: I will remember all this for my next post. Thanks for the reviews